# Remote access to cassandra 4.0.1 using docker via cqlsh

Tags: docker, cassandra

**My Environment:**

- Windows 10 Home
- WSL2
- Cassandra 4.0.1: Official Docker Image

**Docker command:**

```
docker run --name cassandra-node-0 -p 7000:7000 -p 7001:7001 -p 7199:7199 -p 9042:9042 -p 9160:9160 -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=MyCluster -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch -e CASSANDRA_DC=datacenter1 -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=192.168.1.101 -d cassandra
```

**CQLSH Command:**

```
docker run -it -e CQLSH_HOST=$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' cassandra-node-0) --name cassandra-client --entrypoint=cqlsh cassandra
```

I try to connect cassandra node using cqlsh where ubuntu in WSL2 in same pc. 
I did not change all *.yaml file and only use Docker Env. 
When I insert node's docker network ip to CQLSH_HOST, cqlsh is successfully connected node. 
But, When I insert my private ip, public ip or 127.0.0.1, cqlsh is refused connection to node. 
This shows the same issue when nodes from different networks connect.
I think I'm missing a setting of something Docker Env.
**What settings am I missing?** 
**[Update]** I add some port fowarding rules in firewall but same issue.
**[Update 2]** `docker ps -a` result:

```
0.0.0.0:7000-7001->7000-7001/tcp, :::7000-7001->7000-7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7199->7199/tcp, :::7199->7199/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp, :::9042->9042/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9160->9160/tcp, :::9160->9160/tcp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `--hostname` and `--network` when you run Cassandra. For example:

```
$ docker run --rm -d
    --name cassandra-node-0
    --hostname cassandra-node-0
    --network cassandra-node-0
```

You'll find that it's easier to connect via cqlsh by adding:

```
  --network cassandra-node-0
  -e CQLSH_HOST=cassandra-node-0
```

to your `docker run` command. Cheers!